# I just start Heroku with hobby , but i want subdomain with static IP and SSL how can i do?

Tags: heroku

Now i starting to use Heroku with hobby , but i facing problem with SSL

I already add subdomain and using add-on "IPBurger Static IPs"
but i have 2 questions :

1. when i check IP from https://www.whatsmydns.net/ , it still showing like multiple IP. ex:
   23.22.144.165
   23.22.52.7
   3.216.88.24
   3.219.96.23

in case i want to do Whitelist IP, which one is the real outbound IP for my static IP ?

2. I dont see any option to use SSL, how can i add SSL like let's encrypt ?

Thanks so much

Comment: On Heroku, you will not have a static IP, and multiple IPs is the expected and correct behavior. You'd need a paid add-on for a static IP; for example, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic.

Comment: As for SSL: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management